# spring android resttemplate encoding url

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-android

I use Spring android `RestTemplate` to execute GET request to Youtube API like this:

```
// build rest template
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

GsonHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> listHttpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();

listHttpMessageConverters.add(jsonConverter);
listHttpMessageConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
listHttpMessageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(listHttpMessageConverters);

Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels).buildUpon();
uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("key", API_KEY);
uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("part", "id,snippet");
uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("forUsername", channelName);

String url = uriBuilder.build().toString(); // this is right url
// like this:  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=MY_KEY&part=id%2Csnippet&forUsername=cnn

MyEntity result =  restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyEntity.class);
```

From debug, I can see `RestTemplate` execute wrong url and I got `400 bad request error`:

> 03-16 12:06:47.651: W/RestTemplate(24970): GET request for
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=MY_KEY&part=id%252Csnippet&forUsername=cnn"
>   resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler

I have no idea why `RestTemplate` try to encode parameter url again, from `id%2Csnippet` to `id%252Csnippet`
Is there any way to correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just so happens that the `RestTemplate#getForObject(..)` method that expects a `String` builds a URI from the given `String` and encodes it before using it. It uses custom Spring classes to do this. (See the source code.)

You can fix this issue by creating a [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) object from your `String` and pass that to the method.

```
String url = uriBuilder.build().toString(); // this is right url
URI uri = new URI(url);
MyEntity result =  restTemplate.getForObject(uri, MyEntity.class);
```